# Use personal Amazon S3 account to backup Gmail using Ubuntu

Tags: backup, gmail, amazon-s3

As question, I have found online that backupify offer shifting from their S3 to user's personal S3, I have a backupify account but I can't find this options, besides, I don't prefer having my email being processed by somebody else.

Is it possible to use my own personal amazon s3 account to backup Gmail? Preferably as incremental backup, as I don't have to use too much of bandwidth to load redundant data back to S3.

I am using Ubuntu, so script is OK for me.

Comment: Did you ever try out my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Backup G-mail

One option is to use `gmail-backup` from [gmail-backup.com](http://www.gmail-backup.com/).
You can then backup all of your e-mail to `[backupDirectory]` like:

```
gmail-backup backup [backupDirectory] [emailAddress] [password]
```

Where `[backupDirectory]` is some folder where you'll keep a local copy and `[emailAddress]` and `[password]` are how you connect to your Google account.
Note that you'll need to have `imap` enabled in your Gmail settings.

**Incremental Backup:**

Note that you will only be downloading new e-mails (See [Incremental Backup](http://www.gmail-backup.com/incremental-backup)). Each time you run the command, however, you will be checking every e-mail to see if it's new. To help decrease the overhead of looking over ancient e-mails consider adding a date, as in:

```
gmail-backup backup [backupDirectory] [emailAddress] [password] 20110101
```

Also note that it requires `python2.5`. [These instructions](http://kovshenin.com/archives/installing-python-2-5-on-ubuntu-linux-10-10/) may help you meet this requirement.

## Backup to S3

One option is to use `s3cdm` (available in `apt`) from [s3tools.org](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)

```
s3cmd sync --delete-removed --skip-existing [backupDirectory] s3://[s3URL]
```

where `[backupDirectory]` is the same place you just downloaded all of your e-mail, and `[s3URL]` is the URL in your S3 account where you want to place it.

Be sure to take a look at the [`s3cmd` intro page](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd), to learn about first-time setup, and the [`s3cmd` sync documentation](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync) page for more examples. It basically provides `rsync`-like functionality to S3.

Also, note that I've used `--delete-removed` here to delete (from S3) any e-mails that have been permanently deleted there.

**Incremental Backup:**

Note that the `--skip-existing` flag will ensure that you don't re-copy millions of old e-mails to S3.

## Encryption

I'd like to suggest that you also use `encfs` (or some other encryption tool) for something like this. Sending plain-text copies of all of your e-mail to Amazon is not secure. If you use `encfs` you can then sync the encrypted copy instead, while still keeping the incremental backup goal.

Since you use Ubuntu, consider checking out [this tutorial on folder encryption](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption). If you follow their example, in our case you'd want to sync to S3 the folder called `~/encrypted` (not `~/visible`).